# UITableView Section Index Out Of Bounds but it's not really out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Whenever I run the app, the `tableView` has no data, waiting for user to input. The problem is that if the `numberOfSections` is 1, it works just fine, but when I change it to 2 it crashes because Index out of range

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expenseCell") as? ExpenseCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    let budget = userBudget[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.configureCell(budget: budget)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userBudget[section].count // <- Crash here
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Practice with Sections \(section)"
}
```

Comment: What is data in userBudget arrray ?

Comment: There is only one array in `userBudget `. So first the value of `userBudget ` and make sure it have multiple array.

Comment: change your numberOfSections to return userBudget?.count ?? 0(if userBudget is optional) ow userBudget.count. Don't hardcode the value.

Comment: `let userBudget : [[Budget]] = [[]]`

Comment: @PuneetSharma now I get `Index out of bounds` at `let budget = userBudget[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`

Comment: @AndreiVataselu : Is the array getting modified after you reload data?

Comment: @PuneetSharma I have a fetch function and a `tableViewReload` function. The thing is this works just fine as a one-dimmensional array, for rows only, but when I convert it into 2d array it crashes if the section number is bigger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are accessing `index 1` of `userBudget` while i assume it contains `0 index` only.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

This crash happens cause your array **userBudget**, don't has two elements at the moment you try access his second position.

You must guard that userBudget has two elements on minimium...

You should that you must to assign value to userBudget on your ViewDidLoad.

Comment: But how is this possible? As I said, the var **userBudget** was a 1 dimension array and everything worked fine. I set it now to be 2D Array and I'm using only 1 section, so *userBudget[0][indexPath.row]* ,is the same thing as a 1D array, however, this crashes. I can't set it a value into `ViewDidLoad` since the user didn't input anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you will have two section to your tableView's delegate, but you have an array which contains only one array. Basically when you try to reach userBadget[1] in your numberOfRowsInSection function and it crashes because it doesn't exist.

Replace

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

With

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return userBudget.count
}
```